# Which is best approach (JODConverter+open Office or Apache POI HWPF+iText) to convert Microsoft word to PDF in java?

Tags: ms-word, openoffice.org, document-conversion

In my application I have to send automatic emails to the customer when customer status changes.I need to attach a document to that email which should be in the pdf format. I have to create this attached PDF document from a existing word document.Being [Apache Open Office](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Main_Page) is installer and have to be started as a service every time when I want to convert a document I am dilemma to choose between [JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter)+open Office and [Apache POI HWPF](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html) + [iText](http://itextpdf.com/).Please suggest me which to use .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclosure: I lead the docx4j project**

JODConverter + OpenOffice will probably give you the best support for the widest range of features in a **binary .doc** file.  HWPF only supports a restricted subset of .doc content.

If your documents are standard fare paragraphs, tables, images, headers/footers **docx** files, docx4j ought to meet your needs (it includes PDF output via Apache FOP).

Comment: @JasonPluext...thanks for the quick repluy.I went through docx4j documentation.I guess it supports only .docx format. I need to access .doc formats too.

Comment: In which case I'd suggest JODConverter. (docx4j actually uses POI's HWPF for binary .doc, so its capabilities there are much the same as POI's)